# Add ionic <i> tag inside <textarea> tag

Tags: ionic-framework, textarea

I am trying to add ionic tag inside text-area tag of HTML , but the icon placed inside text-area tag doesn't show up for some reasons. If i try to inspect, I am able to find the code related to ionic tag. I am not sure how to  place icon inside the text-area tag.

Comment: a textarea can only contain text, not pictures

Comment: thanks for the clarfication.